# controlling simulink variable timestep size based on signals

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a frequency ramp in Simulink (sin wt  where w increases with time) and would like to use a variable-timestep solver. At the beginning of the simulation, the timesteps could be large; at the end, they have to be small.

I have tried tweaking the relative tolerance and it doesn't really seem to have a useful effect: the timesteps at the end are too long and the sinewaves have only 2-3 points per cycle.

Is there any way to somehow tie the timestep to the sinewave resolution, either directly or indirectly (e.g adding blocks in the simulation to somehow cause timesteps to decrease as frequency increases)?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still interested in this question, a variable-step solver can be forced to hit specific timesteps by setting the `Configuration Parameters > Data Import/Export > Additional parameters> Output options` to `Produce additional output`.  Then set `Output times` to a vector of whatever resolution you desire.  This can also be done programmatically.

For example, if you want 1000 Hz output from 5 to 10 seconds, modify the input object like this:

```
inObj = inObj.setModelParameter("OutputOption","AdditionalOutputTimes");
inObj = inObj.setModelParameter("OutputTimes",[5:0.001:10]);
```

Reference:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/output-options.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to link these two, in that there is not a mechanism to control the solver from the model.  I'm guessing you tried stiff and non-stiff solvers?  Even though your problem may be non-stiff the stiff solver may be better.  Whenever I need this kind of data I use a fixed step solver with very small sample times, but you could make it a little more friendly than that.  I would try something like the following:

Use the `sim` command to set the simulation stop time.

```
simOut = sim('model', 'TimeEnd',10000);
```

You can setup a model that changes a sine wave like this:

[image: Simple Model]

You could change the `logspace` boundaries after each simulation so you would have a loop like:

simulate model
gather the tout, yout, etc. data
change the sample times on the discrete portions of the blocks, just use a single variable.

I think you get the idea, if not let me know!

HTH!